# CakeDC.users: Change default role for new social loged in users

Tags: cakephp, cakedc

I'm using cakeDC.users plugin for CakePHP 3.6.x with social login via google.
Currently the default role for a new user is "user". How can a change this?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the default role of all registered users via configuration file https://github.com/CakeDC/users/blob/master/config/users.php#L43

Override the `Users.Registration.defaultRole` and use the one you would like to use.

Comment: Thx a lot, I've overlooked it.